# Subquery causing 'Invalid use of Null' error

Tags: sql, null, ms-access-2007

I am working with an older bit of code, that I am not the original author of.

The query executed previously, but contained logical errors, therefore returning records which I did not want to return in the query results.

In order to essentially 'filer out' these results, I have a added a subquery. This subquery in the Where clause just looks to see if a given unique key is already in the database. If it is, then that record will NOT be returned in the results---at least, this was my intention.

While I have written and tested the subquery on it's own (it seems to work when run by iteslf) it is causing an 'Invalid use of Null' error when added to the Where criteria of the SQL code which I intend to fix.

Here is the code of the subquery I have written:

```
WHERE (cstr([UBS Reps DTP].[Dealer]) + cstr([UBS Reps DTP].[Dealerbrch]) + cstr([UBS Reps DTP].[Branch Rep ID])) not in 
(
SELECT [Salespage Reps].[Trade_Firm]+[Salespage Reps].[Trade_Office]+[Salespage Reps].[Trade_Rep] AS Expr1
FROM [Salespage Reps]
WHERE ((([Salespage Reps].Trade_Firm)="0000221") AND (([Salespage Reps].Trade_Rep) Is Not Null)) AND (([Salespage Reps].Trade_Office) Is Not Null)
)
```

And here is that subquery added to the rest of the original SQL code:

```
    SELECT dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.REP_NAME, [UBS Reps DTP].[Name First], [UBS Reps DTP].[Name Last], [UBS Reps DTP].[Crd Number], dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.TRADE_FIRM_ORIG, dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.TRADE_OFFICE_ORIG, dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.TRADE_REP_ORIG
FROM dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE LEFT JOIN [UBS Reps DTP] ON (dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.TRADE_OFFICE_ORIG=[UBS Reps DTP].Dealerbrch) AND (dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.TRADE_REP_ORIG=[UBS Reps DTP].[Branch Rep Id])

WHERE (cstr([UBS Reps DTP].[Dealer]) + cstr([UBS Reps DTP].[Dealerbrch]) + cstr([UBS Reps DTP].[Branch Rep ID])) not in 
(
SELECT [Salespage Reps].[Trade_Firm]+[Salespage Reps].[Trade_Office]+[Salespage Reps].[Trade_Rep] AS Expr1
FROM [Salespage Reps]
WHERE ((([Salespage Reps].Trade_Firm)="0000221") AND (([Salespage Reps].Trade_Rep) Is Not Null)) AND (([Salespage Reps].Trade_Office) Is Not Null)
)


GROUP BY dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.REP_NAME, [UBS Reps DTP].[Name First], [UBS Reps DTP].[Name Last], [UBS Reps DTP].[Crd Number], dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.TRADE_FIRM_ORIG, dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.TRADE_OFFICE_ORIG, dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.TRADE_REP_ORIG, dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.ERROR_CODE, dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.ARCHIVE_DATE
HAVING (((dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.TRADE_FIRM_ORIG)="0000221") AND ((dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.ERROR_CODE) Is Not Null) AND ((dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.ARCHIVE_DATE)>Date()-3))
ORDER BY dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.TRADE_OFFICE_ORIG, dbo_TRADE_ARCHIVE.TRADE_REP_ORIG;
```

And here, just to be thorough, is a picture of the error. [image]

It appears that MS Access doesn't like my subquery, because it is concerned that I will be trying to concatenate a null value, and it doesn't know how to handle such values. But to the best of my knowledge, I *have* told MS Access how to handle null values, in my subquery, by telling the subquery to never return a record `WHERE ((([Salespage Reps].Trade_Firm)="0000221") AND (([Salespage Reps].Trade_Rep) Is Not Null)) AND (([Salespage Reps].Trade_Office) Is Not Null)`

I also know for a fact that `(cstr([UBS Reps DTP].[Dealer]) + cstr([UBS Reps DTP].[Dealerbrch]) + cstr([UBS Reps DTP].[Branch Rep ID]))` will never have to handle a null value either, because I have physically checked the linked Excel table for null values (there are none).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's conspicuous is your use of the + operator for what looks to be string concatenation.  For Access SQL/VBA, the & operator is used.  First thing I would try is changing to the ampersand as I think there may be some math issues going on which you didn't intend.

Comment: Just to correct myself, I took a look at the operator list to see what you are trying to accomplish.  There is indeed the + operator for null-value-propogating string concatenation (which I have never used, obviously).  I stand corrected.

Comment: Thanks @VBlades, I have my Access databases set to use SQL Server syntax, if that means anything in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
WHERE (cstr([UBS Reps DTP].[Dealer]) + cstr([UBS Reps DTP].[Dealerbrch]) + cstr([UBS Reps DTP].[Branch Rep ID])) not in
```

to:

```
WHERE (Nz([UBS Reps DTP].[Dealer], "") & Nz([UBS Reps DTP].[Dealerbrch], "") & Nz([UBS Reps DTP].[Branch Rep ID], "")) not in
```

Likely to be an issue with the WHERE concatenation if your subquery is running on its own, I think.  I like using the & operator as it applies the implicit conversion to string.  Nz is like ISNULL in SQL; in this case we will always return a 0-length string if null values are found, so the concatenation operations should never fail.

Comment: FANTASTIC! I was looking for an equivalent version of T-SQL's `isnull`, but was only able to find Access' really (limited) version. Nz is exactly what I never knew I needed.